# How to properly take care of async tasks in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

There is a problem with reusing cells in UITableView:
lets say I have a http request in a cell which may take about 20 seconds to execute. Its completion block effects the cell appearance. User might want to scroll the tableview at this time (while request is executing). After the request has been executed, completion block will effect not a proper cell, because the cells are reused while tableview is scrolling.

Also if you just make a check in the completion block that the cell is the proper one (for example by tagging each cell and checking if it is the same) you will not see a change in the cell appearance when you scroll back to the proper cell.
Do you have any idea of an elegant solution for the problem?

Here is a simplified example of my code which has this problem. It is an IBAction method for a button in a cell which may change the cell by method setInviteStatus

```
- (void)setInviteStatus:(INVITE_STATUS)status withOldTag:(NSInteger)oldTag {//old tag is to change only if cell is related to the invitation, because tableView reuses cells
  if (self.tag != oldTag)
    return;
  switch (status) {
    case INVITE_STATUS_ACCEPTED:
      [self.btnInvite setTitle:@"Accepted" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      break;

    case INVITE_STATUS_INVITE:
      [self.btnInvite setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
      [self.btnInvite setTitle:@"Invite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      break;

    case INVITE_STATUS_REJECTED:
      [self.btnInvite setTitle:@"Rejected" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}

- (IBAction)invitePressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSInteger tag = self.tag; //to save it, it might change due to cell reusing
    [[JLAccountManager sharedManager] inviteUser:tag withCompletion:^(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
      if ([response[ResponseAnswer] isEqual: @YES]) {
        [self setInviteStatus:INVITE_STATUS_ACCEPTED withOldTag:tag];
      } else {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [self setInviteStatus:INVITE_STATUS_INVITE withOldTag:tag];
        });
        [self setInviteStatus:INVITE_STATUS_REJECTED withOldTag:tag];
      }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code snippet so we can understand clearly...Posting some images might be great to understand..

Comment: The usual strategy is to have the completion block update the backing data that's used for cell display and then reload the table's data.  The table is smart enough to only ask you for data for visible cells.  If your updated item isn't being shown and then the user then scrolls to it, you already have fresh information to display.

Comment: @iCrunCher updated

Comment: @PhillipMills this can work.

Comment: @PhillipMills you can post your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Apple has an example for async tableview: [LazyTableImages: Populating UITableView content asynchronously](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)